# Bootable usb from dvd(1:1 copy)

Tags: usb, dvd

i burnt Ubuntu on to a dvd and now the system is kind of not detecting the dvd at the BIOS, so i wanted to make a bootable usb out of the dvd, can somebody help me with this??
PS: i don't have the downloaded file and am reluctant to download it again ;)

Comment: is it an efi computer? did you turn off secure boot?

Answer (score 1):

### Cloning

There are cloning tools that can do the job,

- **in linux [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**

  Maybe the easiest way to use it is to identify the device for the DVD drive. In Ubuntu it is usually `/dev/sr0`. You can find it via the command

  ```
  lsblk -m
  ```

  and then run `dus` (mkusb-dus) in a terminal window.

  ```
  dus /dev/sr0
  ```

  It will guide you via menus until it starts cloning.

  *Tested* `dus` *in June 2017:* cloning DVD disk `/dev/sr0` with Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64
- **in Windows [Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)**

  It is possible to use Win32 Disk Imager in two steps via an iso file,

  - read from the DVD disk to an iso file (with CDBurnerXP or *ImgBurn (tested in June 2017)* or some other tool, that you might have available)
  - write from the iso file to a USB pendrive with *Win32 Disk Imager (tested in June 2017)*

### Extraction

In Windows you can also use **[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie)**, which is an extraction tool.

> Notes on ISO Support:
>
> All versions of Rufus since v1.1.0 allow the creation of a bootable
>   USB from an ISO image (.iso).
>
> Creating an ISO image from a physical disc or from a set of files is
>   very easy to do however, through the use of a CD burning application,
>   such as the freely available CDBurnerXP or ImgBurn.

In other words, the route with Rufus from a DVD disk is also using two steps via an iso file,

- read from the DVD disk to the iso file (with CDBurnerXP or ImgBurn or some other tool, that you might have available)
- extract from the iso file to the USB pendrive with Rufus.